# Code Nuggets, how can I add the following to them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

How can I add the following to code nuggets? <%# #>

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<telerik:RadComboBox id="RadComboBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Also, from the C# code behind, how can I reference id's specified in these code nuggets? Currently it just says that it does not exist.

Thank you.

My attempt:

```
<%# (Condition) ?
"<asp:TextBox id=\"TextBox1\" runat=\"server\" />" +
"<telerik:RadComboBox id=\"RadComboBox1\" runat=\"server\"></telerik:RadComboBox>" :
"N/A" %>
```

Result: Empty page with nothing on it.

Comment: Where/what event are you calling TextBox1 and RadComboBox1 from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code blocks instead of binding expressions

```
<% if(Condition == true){ %>
    <asp:TextBox id="referenceMeInCodeBehindTextbox" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadComboBox id="RadComboBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox> 
<% } %>
```

You can also do it this way (better)

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And manipulate the Visible attribute in the code-behind. If the visibility is false it won't be put onto the page